# How to use timestamp as a variable for FOR loop in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to run a FOR loop for variable value '2023-03-14 03:12:20' till current_timestamp in a stored proc

Can you help me on how to do it

```
do $$
declare
v timestamp;
v1 timestamp ='2023-03-14 03:12:20';
counter timestamp;
begin
for counter in v1..v loop
raise notice 'counter: %', counter;
end loop;
end; $$
```

Comment: Tag-spam cleared.

Comment: `select * from generate_series(...)` might be easier to use and more efficient

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR a IN b..c LOOP` uses [only `integer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR). You'll need to [loop over results of a query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) where you [generate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) your steps:

```sql
do $$
declare
    start   timestamp:='2023-03-14 03:12:20';
    stop    timestamp:=now();
    step    interval :='40 minutes';
    counter timestamp;
begin
    for counter in select generate_series(start,stop,step) loop
        raise notice 'counter: %', counter;
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Or maintain the iterator "manually" in a [`while` loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.7.7):

```sql
do $$
declare
    start   timestamp:='2023-03-14 03:12:20';
    stop    timestamp:=now();
    step    interval :='40 minutes';
    counter timestamp:=start;
begin
    while counter<stop loop
        raise notice 'counter: %', counter;
        counter:=counter+step;
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Note that if you need that to populate a table, for example, you can use generate_series directly, without a plpgsql code block:

```sql
create table t1(c1 int);
insert into t1(c1) select generate_series(12,57,1);
```